# Ignoring Files like config without deleting?

Tags: git, github, gitignore, tortoisegit

I'm using GitHub with TortoiseGit. Currently i just can add files to ignore with "Delete and add to ignorelist". I have a small website project which runs at several customers.
Files like the config-file should be inside the repo/branch but just the initial file with dummy content. When working with on my local i want to ignore changes inside of these files cause i have my own ones and other project workers also.

How i can achieve that? I already treid to add the files manually to the .gitignore but it seems like TortoiseGit doesnt interest the content of that file.

Comment: I dont think that tortoiseGit ignores the .gitignore file. If a file once has been checked in to your local (or remote, doesn't matter) repo, you have to remove it from your repo first with "git rm <filename>". after that it will still exist on your machine but git will ignore it. concerning to your 2nd point: if the file only should contain dummy-content, why dont you just call it dummy-config.txt and dont ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a specific instance of the general question, “How do I ignore changes to tracked files?” which is answered in [the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files):

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

However, the FAQ entry does go on to propose a solution for configuration files where you need to modify the data:

> If your goal is to modify a configuration file, it can often be helpful to have a file checked into the repository which is a template or set of defaults which can then be copied alongside and modified as appropriate. This second, modified file is usually ignored to prevent accidentally committing it.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer of [bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548414/3906760):

1. You can set the skip-worktree flag in TortoiseGit. It is available in the context menu of the files in the [commit dialog](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-commit.html).
2. TortoiseGit comes with a feature called "[changelists](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-changelists.html)". This feature might be handy for you as you can flag a file as "ignore-on-commit". When flagged, this file is not autoselected any more.